# What is the seaplane in this old photograph?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Can you help identify this large apparently water-borne machine?

[image: black and white photograph of some sort of airplane with pontoons over water]

Comment: What is the source of the photograph?

Comment: It’s easy to do a Google Image search: “The Pateras-Pescar-Guidoni seaplane taken in the Royal Arsenal of Venice in 1914” https://www-elicotterienavi-com.translate.goog/aeromobili/STORIA2.HTM?_x_tr_sch=http&_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Comment: More info from Google image search: https://www-airwar-ru.translate.goog/enc/bww1/pescaraguidoni.html?_x_tr_sch=http&_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Comment: For those who have never used Google Image search it's on the Google Home page, on the right side of the search bar is what looks like some type of colorful plant, that's actually a microphone for voice command, to the right of that is a sort of multi-colored box with a couple of dots on it, that's supposed to be a camera, click that, on the next screen click Upload a File, from there you can select a photo that you have downloaded to your PC.  As for the icon, I guess the dot in the middle is a lens, rectangle on top is a viewfinder, dot on the lower right is - stop down metering button?

Answer (score 2):

Google Image search led me to [this website](https://www.airwar.ru/enc/bww1/pescaraguidoni.html), which indicates it's the

**Pescara-Guidoni Torpedo Seaplane**